# Convert any String time to seconds

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert 15:00 (15minutes) to seconds though I get 54,000 when I use this below.

I'm trying to convert 15minutes to seconds.

```
S = '15:00';
D = "1/1/1 "
s = ( new Date(D+S) - new Date(D) )/1000
alert(s);
```

Though when I do the math, it's 60 x 15 = 900. How do I get 900, since the time is a random string.

Comment: `alert(s / 60);` ... 900

Comment: 900 minutes are 54000 seconds... seems to be all good to me.

Comment: 15 hours x 60 mn x 60 secs = 54,000.........

Comment: oh, no its 15minutes, not hours. 900 seconds is 15minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if your format will always be "mm:ss" you could dome string parsing and do the math manually, of course this would need to be adjusted depending on the input format.

```
S = '15:25';
var times = S.split(":");
var minutes = times[0];
var seconds = times[1];
seconds = parseInt(seconds, 10) + (parseInt(minutes, 10) * 60);
alert(seconds);​
```

Note in the example I explicitly added 25 seconds just as demonstration.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jg4gB/

Comment: thankyou, this is what I eventually used. function TimeToSeconds(t){
    var r = t.split(":");
    if(r.length==2){
        a = r[0] * 60;
        b = r[1] * 1;
        return a + b;
    }else if(r.length==3){
        a = r[0] * 3600;
        b = r[1] * 60;
        c = r[2] * 1;
        return a + b + c;
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

The time string '15:00' in JavaScript refers to the time of day 1500hr, or 3:00 p.m. American-style.  That's 15 hours after midnight.  That explains why you got 54,000 seconds.

If you wanted to express 15 minutes using your method of manipulating date strings, try '00:15:00'.

Comment: This better suits as a comment. :)

Comment: Perhaps, but the little flyover on the "Add Comment" link says it should be used for asking the OP for clarification on the post.  The OP seemed to be asking a direct question, namely "why do I get 54,000 when I _thought_ I was expressing 15 minutes in a time string?"  Since the question was very direct I thought an answer was better.  No clarification on the question was needed IMHO.